# Nginx response trouble when aliasing to a specific file with regex

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

Basically, I'm trying to handle nice URLs mapped to actual HTML files on the server.

I have URLs like so:

```
/posts/nice-blog-post/
```

That need to return an HTML file on the filesystem like:

```
/path/to/site/posts/nice-blog-post.html
```

The location directive I have so far is:

```
location ^~ /(.*)/$ {
    alias /path/to/site/$1.html;
}
```

This sort of works, except only the following URL successfully resolves:

```
domain.com/posts/nice-blog-post
```

This URL (with trailing slash) returns a 404:

```
domain.com/posts/nice-blog-post/
```

So I have two issues:

1. How do I get the URL with trailing slash resolving correctly?
2. More importantly, when nginx handles the alias, it doesn't appear to return any response headers. The HTML file is then downloaded as a file rather than being rendered to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regular expression, so it will handle both ways - with and without slash. Should be something like this I suppose:

```
location ^~ /(.*)/?$ {
    alias /path/to/site/$1.html;
}
```